# Cannot find MODULES or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: angular, datepicker

i tried using this code from angular datepicker documentation and i received some error regarding `moment` from imports, after i installed it nothing has changed but i received more errors for my imports that worked fine until installing `moment`. what can i do, i tried using `npm install --save @angular/core` and `npm install --save` but i still receive errors

```
import {Component, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import {MomentDateAdapter, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS} from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import {DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE} from '@angular/material/core';
import {MatDatepicker} from '@angular/material/datepicker';

// Depending on whether rollup is used, moment needs to be imported differently.
// Since Moment.js doesn't have a default export, we normally need to import using the `* as`
// syntax. However, rollup creates a synthetic default module and we thus need to import it using
// the `default as` syntax.
import * as _moment from 'moment';
// tslint:disable-next-line:no-duplicate-imports
import {default as _rollupMoment, Moment} from 'moment';

const moment = _rollupMoment || _moment;

// See the Moment.js docs for the meaning of these formats:
// https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/
export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'MM/YYYY',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'MM/YYYY',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};

/** @title Datepicker emulating a Year and month picker */
@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-views-selection-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-views-selection-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['datepicker-views-selection-example.css'],
  providers: [
    // `MomentDateAdapter` can be automatically provided by importing `MomentDateModule` in your
    // application's root module. We provide it at the component level here, due to limitations of
    // our example generation script.
    {
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useClass: MomentDateAdapter,
      deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS],
    },

    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS},
  ],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class DatepickerViewsSelectionExample {
  date = new FormControl(moment());

  setMonthAndYear(normalizedMonthAndYear: Moment, datepicker: MatDatepicker<Moment>) {
    const ctrlValue = this.date.value!;
    ctrlValue.month(normalizedMonthAndYear.month());
    ctrlValue.year(normalizedMonthAndYear.year());
    this.date.setValue(ctrlValue);
    datepicker.close();
  }
}
```

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Month and Year</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dp" [formControl]="date">
  <mat-hint>MM/YYYY</mat-hint>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="dp"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #dp
                  startView="multi-year"
                  (monthSelected)="setMonthAndYear($event, dp)"
                  panelClass="example-month-picker">
  </mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

[image: errors]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is working after running `npm i --save-dev @types/babel__core`